# Radio Buttons 1 - 10 : With Simple Form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, simple-form

I need a simple_form that has options 1-10. I was trying the following:

```
 <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :cost, [1..10] %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose this would work as well.

```
<%= f.input :cost, collection: (1..10), as: :radio_buttons, boolean_style: :inline %>
```

Answer (score 0):

So easy:

```
 <%= f.input :cost, collection: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], as: :radio_buttons, boolean_style: :inline %>
```